# error running python websocket library example code

Tags: python, websocket

i am having an error with the example code provided and i have not found anything on google, here is the traceback

```
ERROR:websockets.server:Error in connection handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\felix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\websockets\server.py", line 84, in handler
    yield from self.ws_handler(self, path)
  File "C:\Users\felix\Desktop\letistry\server.py", line 45, in counter
    async for message in websocket:
TypeError: 'async for' requires an object with __aiter__ method, got WebSocketServerProtocol
```

all i have done is copy and paste code from https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html

im running the Synchronization example (code follows) on python 3.6 on windows 10.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# WS server example that synchronizes state across clients

import asyncio
import json
import logging
import websockets

logging.basicConfig()

STATE = {'value': 0}

USERS = set()

def state_event():
    return json.dumps({'type': 'state', **STATE})

def users_event():
    return json.dumps({'type': 'users', 'count': len(USERS)})

async def notify_state():
    if USERS:       # asyncio.wait doesn't accept an empty list
        message = state_event()
        await asyncio.wait([user.send(message) for user in USERS])

async def notify_users():
    if USERS:       # asyncio.wait doesn't accept an empty list
        message = users_event()
        await asyncio.wait([user.send(message) for user in USERS])

async def register(websocket):
    USERS.add(websocket)
    await notify_users()

async def unregister(websocket):
    USERS.remove(websocket)
    await notify_users()

async def counter(websocket, path):
    # register(websocket) sends user_event() to websocket
    await register(websocket)
    try:
        await websocket.send(state_event())
        async for message in websocket:
            data = json.loads(message)
            if data['action'] == 'minus':
                STATE['value'] -= 1
                await notify_state()
            elif data['action'] == 'plus':
                STATE['value'] += 1
                await notify_state()
            else:
                logging.error(
                    "unsupported event: {}", data)
    finally:
        await unregister(websocket)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
    websockets.serve(counter, 'localhost', 6789))
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Comment: There are so many examples on the page, I am afraid no one will give suggestions if you cannot clean up and paste them to your question...

Comment: what needs cleaning up? should i post the code from the example here? thanks for your comment

Comment: yeah, this will make your question more likely to be answered, people will move to other posts if they need to find the code from other place with a lots of code. You need to give a minimal workable code which can reproduce your issues.

Comment: have install other websocket lib?

Comment: im not sure.. is this likely to make a difference? might they interfere?

Comment: code works on python 3.7

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in a dependency library, `telethon`, according to this thread:

https://github.com/expectocode/telegram-export/issues/33

So this may occur if you're using outdated packages that come with your distribution, for example. Using `virtualenv` and making sure I was using the most recent packages via `pip` inside the virtual environment solved the problem for me.

Specifically, the version installed with package `python3-websockets` on Ubuntu 18.04 is currently 3.4-1. Using `pip` in a virtual environment, the version is 8.0.3.